# ActiveRecord: Why and How are Client.take vs Client.take! (exclamation point) different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference in ActiveRecord between

'take' vs 'take!' (includes exclamation point).

I think the difference is that the exclamation point is more paranoid and raises "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" rather than returning nil.

SOURCE: [[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object%5D)

aside:
I had previously thought that "!" meant updates to the table, but I guess "!" means different things in different situations.

To take and erase a record, I guess you would run

```
a=Client.take
# do what needs to be done to this record
a.destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`take!` just raises an exception if no record is found.  See docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-take-21